# Spring JMS Listener Container stop only half of listeners

Tags: spring, jms, jboss7.x, hornetq, spring-jms

I have weired problem with a JMS Listener container. In case I disable the listener container, half of messages are delivered and processed by listener. Here is my Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="ConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="JmsXA" />
</bean>

<bean id="testQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="queue/test" />
</bean>

<bean id="listener" class="eu.cuptech.jms.listener.ExampleListener" />

<bean id="listenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="ConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="testQueue" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="listener" />
    <property name="concurrency" value="1" />
</bean>
```

**ExampleListener** is here:

```
package eu.cuptech.jms.listener;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class ExampleListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            String msg = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            System.out.println("MESSAGE TEXT: " + msg);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Client is Spring MVC Controller with following methods:

**send10Messages** method (common JMS client):

```
@Resource(name="ConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Resource(name="testQueue")
private Queue testQueue;

@RequestMapping(value="send10", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String send10Messages(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) throws Exception {
    sendTextMessages(10, "Test message: ");
    return "redirect:/info";
}

private void sendTextMessages(int count, final String prefix) throws Exception {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer messageProducer = null;
    try {
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        messageProducer = session.createProducer(testQueue);
        connection.start();
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < count) {
            message.setText(prefix + ++i);
            messageProducer.send(message);
            Thread.sleep(250);
            System.out.println("Message " + prefix + i + " sent.");
        }

    } finally {
        try {
            if (messageProducer != null)
                messageProducer.close();
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
            if (session != null)
                session.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**disableListener** method:

```
@Resource(name="listenerContainer")
private DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer;

@RequestMapping(value="disableListener", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String disableListener(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
    listenerContainer.stop(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("JMS Listener stopped.");
        }
    });
    return "redirect:/info";
}
```

**enableListener** method

```
@Resource(name="listenerContainer")
private DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer;

@RequestMapping(value="enableListener", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String enableListener(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
    listenerContainer.start();
    return "redirect:/info";
}
```

When I start server and send messages I got this log (It is OK):

```
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 1
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 1 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 2
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 2 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 3
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 3 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 4
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 4 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 5
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 5 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 6
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 6 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 7
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 7 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 8
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 8 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 9
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 9 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 10
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 10 sent.
```

When I disable the listener container and send messages again I got this:

```
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) JMS Listener stopped.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 1
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 1 sent.
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 2 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 3
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 3 sent.
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 4 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 5
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 5 sent.
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 6 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 7
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 7 sent.
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 8 sent.
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 9
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 9 sent.
INFO [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Message Test message: 10 sent.
```

When I enable the listener container again I got this:

```
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 2
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 4
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 6
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 8
INFO [stdout] (listenerContainer-1) MESSAGE TEXT: Test message: 10
```

The problem is that every odd message is processed by listener even if listener is disabled. I expact that all messages will be delivered and processed by listener when I enable the listener container and no message will be processed when I disable it.

I'm using Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE (I was trying 3.2.3.RELEASE too), HornetQ 2.3.0.Final as remote JMS Server and JBoss 7.3.1.Final as App server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are loading the container into both the web context (`DispatcherServlet`'s context) and the root context (`ContextLoaderListener`'s context). Which means you have 2 containers and you are only stopping the one in the servlet context.

Turn on `DEBUG` logging for `org.springframework` and examine the bean initialization logs.

It probably should be just in the root context.

Comment: You're completely right. I had same config file used by `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`. I started with Mkyong's [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/) which set it up. Thank you.

Comment: It probably also means there is some kind of prefetch/consumer caching going on in the connection factory you get from JNDI - that would explain why the 5 messages are "stuck" waiting for that specific container to start again.